# Check if value is any of the type's fields

Tags: typescript

All too often in TypeScript I run into a situation where I have an interface for an object:

```
interface MyType {
  property1: string
  property2: string
}
```

and when I do something like this:

```
const handleAction = (key: string, value: string) => {
  const myObject: MyType = {property1: "a", property2: "b"}
  myObject[key] = value
}
```

I get an error `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'MyType'`.

I understand that I could declare the function input as `key: propert1 | property2`, but this is annoying, and I can misspell.

Is it possible in TypeScript to somehow indicate `key: any_field_of_MyType` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `keyof MyType` for the type of the parameter:

```typescript
interface MyType {
  property1: string
  property2: string
}

const handleAction = (key: keyof MyType, value: string) => {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^
  const myObject: MyType = {property1: "a", property2: "b"}
  myObject[key] = value
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAUMsjlAPZ5RjoCMAXMgM5hSgDmxpFVNATIxZsQnAL6FCCciBbIAFnBAATADYQAggjDBpyALzIAFAGsI6RqfTkYaLLggAaZADc4KgK4RBrDgEp9AHzIRCRSMmDIALboAPIARgBWEFqMGNh4+sFklNA0DMgARHAFTtm86AKFcQXiJNHxSVoA2pYAupmuHhCEokA)

`keyof` is described and discussed in varous parts of the [advanced types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) page in the handbook.

You could also derive `value`'s type from `MyType` by using generics:

```typescript
const handleAction = <Key extends keyof MyType>(key: Key, value: MyType[Key]) => {
  const myObject: MyType = {property1: "a", property2: "b"}
  myObject[key] = value
}
```

That's more useful with an interface where the type of the value varies rather than just being `string`, but... *(Thank you [Aleksey L.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113002/aleksey-l) for pointing out how generics make that work well!)*

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAUMsjlAPZ5RjoCMAXMgM5hSgDmxpFVNATIxZsQnAL6FCCciBbIAFnBAATADYQAggjDBpyALzIAPAGkI6ZBAAekZU2QBrM+RhosuCAD4AFI-SNT6AA0yABucCoArhCMGNh4ANoBALoAlPoeyEQkUjJgyAC26ADyAEYAVhBaMW54+plklNA0DMgARHCtwQ286AJtJa3iJIWlFVrxvkl1YZEQhKJAA)

Comment: Generics can help to match a value type with the key `const handleAction = <Key extends keyof MyType>(key: Key, value: MyType[Key])`

Comment: @AlekseyL. - Oh, that's a major improvement, thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

The `MyType` contains two properties namely `property1` and `property2`. When you want to access a field on the object using `key: string`, TS raises error because `key` can be any string(infinite possibilities) but only two properties exist.

Now, if you can restrict `key` to take keys of `MyType` by doing this

```js
interface MyType {
  property1: string
  property2: string
}

const handleAction = (key: keyof MyType, value: string) => {
  const myObject: MyType = {property1: "a", property2: "b"}
  myObject[key] = value
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAUMsjlAPZ5RjoCMAXMgM5hSgDmxpFVNATIxZsQnAL6FCCciBbIAFnBAATADYQAggjDBpyALzIAFAGsI6RqfTkYaLLggAaZADc4KgK4RBrDgEp9AHzIRCRSMmDIALboAPIARgBWEFqMGNh4+sFklNA0DMgARHAFTtm86AKFcQXiJNHxSVoA2pYAupmuHhCE4oQKymqa2tKGAORluXSjTqNwcQijvn2KqhpaOiBjE9ToAMzTyLPzi8gA9KfI0BRQ3Dk7u8hK5BBMyCDkERAAHsAsQA)